# Java project can't find file

Tags: java, file, io

I have a project that finds a text file and makes it into an array of characters. However, for some reason or another it isn't finding the file. This is all the code involving opening/reading the file:

```
public void initialize(){
    try{
    File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/worlds/world1.txt").toString());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(file),
                Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    int c;
    for(int i = 0; (c = reader.read()) != -1; i ++) {
      for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++){
          worlds[1][x][i] = (char) c;
          c = reader.read();
      }
    }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When ran, it shows in the console that it is pointing to the correct file, but claims nothing exists there. I've checked, and the file is completely intact and in existence. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: You should use `toURI()` instead of `toString()`. But for better answer look at @Raffaele post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not get a resource like that. You can use

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    getClass().getResourceAsStream("/worlds/world1.txt")
));
```

Also, be careful when you package your application if you develop it inside an IDE, otherwise you'll run into common `CLASSPATH` troubles

Answer (score 0):

File path for embedded resources is calculated from the package root folder. Assuming that `src` folder is the root package folder, make sure, that `world1.txt` file is located at `src/worlds/` folder and full path is `src/worlds/world1.txt`

Second point, use the following code to obtain embedded file reader object:

```
// we do not need this line anymore
// File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/worlds/world1.txt").toString());

// use this approach
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            getClass().getResourceAsStream("/worlds/world1.txt"),
            Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't indicated where your file lives.

`getClass().getResource` is used to locate a resource/file on your classpath; the resource may be packaged in your jar, for example.  In this case, you can't open it as a `File`; see Raffaele's response.

If you want to locate the resource/file on the file system, then create the File object directly without `getResource()`:

> new File("/worlds/world1.txt")

Answer (score 0):

I was using Netbeans and I was getting similar results. When I defined the file Path from the C drive and ran my code it stated: Access has been denied.

The following code ran fine, just back track your file location to the source (src) file.

```
//EXAMPLE FILE PATH
String filePath = "src\\solitaire\\key.data";

try {
    BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

    String lineText = null;

    while ((lineText = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
        hand.add(lineText);

        System.out.println(lineText); // Test print of the lines
    }

    lineReader.close(); // Closes the bufferReader

    System.out.print(hand); // Test print of the Array list
} catch(IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Comment: Though you may use a `try`-with-resources block since you're using a `BufferedReader`: `try (BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {`. By the way, welcome to [so]! Don't forget to take a [tour] :)